# Intl.NumberFormat.formatToParts does not exist on Edge

Tags: javascript, number-formatting, missing-features

As you can see below, `Intl.NumberFormat.formatToParts` seems to be missing from Microsoft Edge:
[image: formatToParts in Microsoft Edge]

However, both [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat/formatToParts) and [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#search=numberformat) tell me I can...

What am I supposed to do? I can't seem to find any website speaking about this issue, nor can I find a polyfill (EDIT: a polyfill is actually available on MDN, but as I said in my last phrase, I am more interested in the reasons why this method is missing whereas both MDN and CanIUse say it is available on Edge).

I am using it like this:

```
return (_numberFormat as any).formatToParts(val).map(({type, value}) => {
    if (type === 'group')
        return ' ';

    return value;
}).reduce((string, part) => string + part);
```

(all I am doing is using a proper space character instead of the unicode default one, which is too slim for the liking of my client)

I know I could work around this (performing a basic format, and replacing the unicode space myself afterwards, or implementing a polyfill), but I am far more intrigued by the fact that this method does not seem to exist on Edge whereas everyone on Earth seems convinced that it does.

Any input appreciated :)

Kind regards,

Comment: Hmm.. According to this (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat), it is available though..

Comment: @wentjun Precisely what I said :) But it is *not* available, though. And I am surprised that no one seems to be talking about it missing in Edge, anywhere on the web.

Comment: Most people these days are using a build pipeline that goes through babel outputting ES5 so you can use the latest TypeScript and ES6 syntax but your build is compatible with all ES5 browsers.

Comment: Thx @AdrianBrand, I am among these people, and I use TypeScript as you may have guessed from the code snippet. Another thing you may have guessed is that `formatToParts` is missing from TS, well at least from the version I am currently using (hence the `as any` trick). I'm not quite sure what EcmaScript version I am transpiling my TS files to, I'd have to double-check that. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Check the "target": "es5" under compiler options in your tsconfig.json file.

Comment: @AdrianBrand thx for the help! I'll first update my TS version though, because if TS does not know about `NumberFormat.formatToParts`, my guess is it won't work anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods really are missing in Edge:

```js
console.log(typeof Intl.NumberFormat.prototype.formatToParts);
console.log(typeof Intl.DateTimeFormat.prototype.formatToParts);
```

lists the prototype property types as `function` in Firefox and `undefined` in Edge.

*Possibly* the MDN article was mislead by Microsoft typing the functions in TypeScript (which has nothing to do with them being implemented in Edge) and [listing the issue as fixed](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25069).

---

Note that google links for MSDN articles on formatToParts now simply redirect to MDN.

---

*Update regarding listing of Edge support on MDN (https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data/pull/3769) (reported in comment by foolip).*

Testing and investigation confirms `formatFromParts` support was added in [Edge 18](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide).

However this had not been pushed to my machine through Windows Update as of April 09 2019 (yesterday), and Edge is showing its version information as "Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0 EdgeHTML 17.134" under (hamburger dots > settings > about this app). Googling "has windows 1810 been pushed through windows update" reveals a troublesome history which goes as long way to explaining why I am still running Win 1803  and Edge 17.

I suggest the [support page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat/formatToParts#Browser_compatibility) would benefit by  replacing "yes" for Edge support with "18" to remove the confusion.

Comment: According to this issue (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25069), it seems to be fixed in TypeScript, which means I must be running an old version of TS (hence the `(_numberFormat as any).formatToParts`).I decided to use a monospace font so that the thousands separator is wide enough for my client. Thanks for your input!

Comment: `Intl.NumberFormat.prototype.formatToParts` and `Intl.DateTimeFormat.prototype.formatToParts` do exist in Edge 18. See https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data/pull/3769#issuecomment-481200672 for discussion of this issue in MDN.

Comment: @foolip thanks for the link which helped add detail to  the answer.